# Changing video tag source video.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-video, video.js

I am working on a HD button, so I have to reload the video and play it when it stops. So first, I am trying to load the HD file.
I've already read a lot of things about changing the source of the video tag. My code is working with FireFox and Internet Explorer, but not with Chrome :

```
vjs.HdToggle.prototype.onClick = function() {
    var mp4Vid = document.getElementById('mp4Source');
    var webmVid = document.getElementById('webmSource');
    var oggVid = document.getElementById('oggSource');
    this.player_.pause();
    $(mp4Vid).attr('src', './test.mp4');
    $(webmVid).attr('src', './test.webm');
    $(oggVid).attr('src', './test.ogg');
    this.player_.load();
    this.player_.play();
}
```

I don't know what I have to do to make it work with Chrome. Does somebody have an idea ?
Thank you, Lea.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `src()` to update the sources.

```
this.player_.src([
  { type: "video/mp4", src: "/test.mp4" },
  { type: "video/webm", src: "/video.webm" },
  { type: "video/ogg", src: "/test.ogv" }
]);
```

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#src-source-

You might also find this existing plugin useful: https://github.com/vidcaster/video-js-resolutions

Comment: Thank you for answering me @misterben. Do you know if this plugin works with one of the last version of video.js ? Because it will be perfect!

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it looks like it's made for video.js 4.x. There's a note there that it only works with the dev version of video.js.